No consigo importar bootstrap a mi proyecto con angular 17
Estoy intentando importar bootstrap a mi proyecto angular17 pero no funciona.
He creado mi proyecto de angular normal, luego he instalado bootstrap con npm install bootstrap@5.3.3 y despues en el archivo angular.json he importado en styles en el la ruta relativa del archivo bootstrap.min.css que es node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css, de la misma forma he importado la ruta relativa del archivo js de bootstrap y lo he importado en scripts en el archivo angular.json, para probar si funcionaba he usado estos botones propios de bootstrap
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Primary</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Secondary</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Success</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Danger</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">Warning</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info">Info</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-light">Light</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-dark">Dark</button>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-link">Link</button>

Pero en la pagina se ven solo los botones sin ninguna clase añadida como si no reconociera las clases de bootstrap:

A que se debe esto?

He conseguido solucionar el problema, respondo para que aquellos que les pase lo mismo en mi caso ha funcionado esto, en vez de usar el comando npm install bootstrap@5.3.3, he usado npm i bootstrap y despues he repetido el proceso de importar los archivos correspondientes de styles y scripts como he hecho arriba y esta vez ya si ha funcionado. Resumiendo si te ha pasado lo mismo que a mí repite el proceso de arriba sustituyendo el comando npm install bootstrap@5.3.3 por npm i bootstrap.

Ese es el proceso normal de instalación de Boostrap...; lo cual se tenía que haber verificado antes de hacer la pregunta.

@René, por otra parte, ¿quién lee la documentación?

He visto un video en youtube como muchos de los PRINCIPIANTES como yo hacen, ya que al empezar se hace muy cuesta arriba ver pura documentación, en ese video por algún motivo me enseñaba a iniciar bootstrap de la forma que hice arriba exactamente, después de buscar información encontré la forma correcta y simplemente he querido aportar por si algun PRINCIPIANTE como yo que no tenemos experiencia alguna en el mundo de la programación y de repente esta en la misma situación que yo pueda guiarse y ayudarse del comentario, de todas formas tomo su "consejo" de leer la documentación la próxima vez.

Entiendo que al empezar es fácil recurrir a videos. Sin embargo, es fundamental que desde el principio consultes la documentación oficial. Es la fuente más precisa y evitará problemas como el que tuviste. Muchas de hechas incluso tienen tutoriales detallados.
Mi consejo sería que, aunque uses videos, siempre verifiques la información en la documentación para asegurarte de seguir buenas prácticas, principalmente porque aprender a investigar es una habilidad clave en programación.
